Login error despite giving the correct credentials with playwright. and this only happens with one specific website
So im trying to log in to a website to further automate it... but the problem is despite me providing the correct username and password the page throws and error when i perform sign in. Yes i have cross checked if the password was right multiple times.
so the code goes like this,
page.fill("Locator","username")
page.fill("Locator","password")
Locator signin=page.locate("locator for signin button");
page.click(signin);

    

the username and password will get populated i the input fields and when sign in is performed it throws iUsername or Password is incorrect.
I was expecting it to smoothly log in to the page which clearly did not work for some reason.

Is this website available to public so others can try to reproduce your issue?
